# javascript - display in a random order everytime page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html

What should I do to make this display in a random order every time the page is refreshed.

here's what I added on my WordPress text editor and it displays the images perfectly fine but it does not randomize the order of the divs. What did I do wrong?

```
<br><br>
<div class="quiz">
<a href="http://www.thequizmania.com/we-bet-you-cant-pass-this-tricky-general-knowledge-quiz/">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/3YcBoyN.jpg"></img>
<a>
</div>

<br>
<div class="quiz">
<a href="http://www.thequizmania.com/what-kind-of-traveler-are-you/">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/GZn9myC.jpg"></img>
<a>
</div>

<br>
<div class="quiz">
<a href="http://www.thequizmania.com/what-two-words-describe-you-as-a-mother/">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/QnJezBF.jpg"></img>
<a>
</div>

<br>
<div class="quiz">
<a href="http://www.thequizmania.com/can-you-pick-the-correct-word/">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Pdi9dyo.jpg"></img>
<a>
</div>

<br>
<div class="quiz">
<a href="http://www.thequizmania.com/can-you-pass-this-almost-impossible-shapes-test/">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ov5WdOg.jpg"></img>
<a>
</div>

<br>

<script>
var cards = $(".quiz");
for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length -1) + 1;
    var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length -1) +1;
    cards.eq(target).before(cards.eq(target2));
}
</script>
```

Comment: By the way, you did not close tag ```<a>``` anywhere

Comment: Well thank you for that @Optio yet that still didn't help.

Comment: You could get the number of elements with the class `quiz` and create an array with the numbers of 1 - n which are randomly sorted and then you could refer to this array of randomized numbers to sort your elements random. have a look at @Mehul Mohan s answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine.
I just:

1. Fixed `<a>` tag
2. Added Jquery library

[Here your code on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ve1Lp7zq/)

Comment: @TevelZaki If all is ok - just mark this answer as right.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomize it with `Math.random`.

```js
  var divContents = ['<br><div class="quiz"><a href="http://www.thequizmania.com/can-you-pass-this-almost-impossible-shapes-test/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ov5WdOg.jpg"></a></div>', 'second', 'thrid', '4th', '5th', '6th'];
  var len = divContents.length;
  var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
  
  for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(divContents.length));
    parent.innerHTML += (divContents[random]);
    divContents.splice(random, 1);
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">

</div>
```